# Unknown Column in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

The following code is responsible for the MySQL error `Error In Insert-->Unknown column 'expert manager' in 'field list'`. If I remove the code below it will solve the MySQL error. Do you know what's wrong with this piece of code?

```
$l=0;
$source = 'expertmanager';
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `student_questions` WHERE user_id=".$userId."");

for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) 
{   
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `student_questions` (`user_id`, `checked_id`, `category_id`, course_id, `question`, `exe_order`, `time`,course_code, year, school, status, close, source) VALUES ('".$userId."', '".$_POST['checkbox'][$i]."', ".$this->cat.", ".$course_id.",'".$_SESSION['question']."','".(++$l)."', '".$time."', '".$course_code."', '".$year."', '".$school."', 1, ".$close.", ".$source.")") or die("Error In Insert-->".mysql_error()); 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, the code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: `".$source."` => `'".$source."'`, but heed Pekka's advice....

Comment: Are there any ON INSERT triggers against this table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrong with this piece of code:

#### Too short variable names

Don't use variable names that are shorter than 3-5 chars. Every variable name should describe the value(s) you want to store inside.

```
//bad
$l=0;
//good
$executionOrder = 0;
```

#### Concatenation of queries

Don't concatenate queries, it's a bad practice that leads to errors, insecure applications, etc. Don't use the mysql API either, it's outdated, insecure and will be deprecated. Use PDO and prepared statements instead.

```
//bad
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `student_questions` WHERE user_id=".$userId."");

//good
$statement = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM `student_questions` WHERE user_id = ?);
$statement->execute(array($userId));
```

#### Usage of die()

I see it all the time, and I see people telling other people to do that all the time. It's plain simply bad practice and it's time that people start to understand this. You cannot catch the error in any way. You cannot log the error. You cannot control whether it should be output to the screen or not. It's okay to do that in a development environment, but certainly not in a production environment.

#### You're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

NEVER, NEVER include user data (session, get, post, cookie, etc.) unfiltered/unescaped into your queries.

```
//really bad
$query = "SELECT something FROM table WHERE " . $_POST['someValue'];

//better
$query = "SELECT something FROM table WHERE " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['someValue']);

//even better: use prepared statements as shown above
```

#### And finally the smallest thing that's wrong and the one that created your error

```
//bad
$query = "INSERT INTO `student_questions` (source) VALUES (expertmanager)"; //that's what you have

//better
$query = "INSERT INTO `student_questions` (source) VALUES ('expertmanager')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a column called expert manager? If so, try changing the name to 'expert_manager' (without quotes), and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You have not enclosed the value of `$source` (which is the string `expert_manager`) in single quotes in your query.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `student_questions` (...snip...) VALUES (...snip...'".$school."', 1, ".$close.", '".$source."')") or die("Error In Insert-->".mysql_error()); 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

We cannot see the value of `$close`, but if it is a string value rather than numeric, it should probably be enclosed in quotes as well.

Additional note:  I see `$_POST['checkbox'][$i]` passed directly into the query.  Please make sure this input has been properly validated and escaped with `mysql_real_escape_string()` if necessary.  The same rule may apply to other variables used in the `VALUES()` list, but we cannot see their origins with the code posted.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot quotes around several values in your insert statement :

```
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) 
{   
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `student_questions` (`user_id`, `checked_id`, `category_id`, course_id, `question`, `exe_order`, `time`,course_code, year, school, status, close, source) VALUES ('".$userId."', '".$_POST['checkbox'][$i]."', '".$this->cat."', '".$course_id."','".$_SESSION['question']."','".(++$l)."', '".$time."', '".$course_code."', '".$year."', '".$school."', 1, '".$close."', '".$source."')") or die("Error In Insert-->".mysql_error()); 
}
```

Not only $source, there are also : $course_id, $close, etc.